# Do I need an isolated DC-DC converter for this design?

Tags: battery-operated

Do I have to use isolated DC converters for that design or single DC SFDC CONVERTERS'

**Simple schematic for a LiFePO4 4 cells module balancer**

[image: simple shematics for a lifepo4 4 cells module balancer]

**Expanded view of converters:**

[image]

this design is to use like simple and active cell balancing system in 4 cells module stackable

Comment: It's great that you have posted a block diagram.  Please add some description of what you are trying to accomplish.  Also, what isolated from what?  On a different note, please don't write in all capitals.

Comment: thanks for editing, i am french and mi english is not good but just look for help, here nobody answer that kind of questions, and an engeneer is not esay to contact, less in forums. thanks for your help. I am trying to developp an efficient and simple active cells balancing system, best regards

Answer (score 2):

Because your converters have to be referenced to separate batteries, then yes, absolutely they need to be isolated. If they aren't, they will connect the negative ends of each battery to each other and to ground.

Comment: +1 for being able to read English more than 1 SD from mean, unlike many, and being able and willing to answer the obvious question.

Comment: Whoops :-) - 1st attempt said "unable" in error :-).

Comment: thanks for your answer, that design is for use on an active cell balancing system. Actually the use of bidirectional converters is too difficult for mi budget and knowledge capacity, really cool best regards